# Element background, both color and an image, is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am wondering if it's possible to have both a background color and an image for an element.

**Like this:**

```
background:#666;
background:url("nav-icon") no-repeat;
right:10px; top:10px;
```

For the moment it ignores the first background statement: `background:#666;`

Thanks Jack

Comment: `background:` is shorthand for `background-color`, `background-image`, `background-position` etc. and you can set each of those to whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background` is a shorthand property for all background styles, try this:

```
background: #666 url("nav-icon") 10px 10px no-repeat;
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: thanks for your respond, than it ignores the right:10px;top:10px; ;/

Comment: You don't need to reference top or right in your style, if you are looking to position the background image... I've updated my answer.

Comment: The two 10 px values will position the image, chane the second value to 0

Comment: this solution works great, but can someone explain the position values abit more, they don't work like this, :top right bottom left?

Comment: When explicit values (either % or px) are used, they are measured from the top-left origin (0,0) of the container, the first is horizontal, the second is vertical; sortof like cartesian coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use

Give Full property names i.e.

```
   background-color:#666; ( instead of only background)
```

and

```
   background-image:url('nav-icon');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:10px 10px 0 0;
```